# Disabling Adobe Flash in enterprise environment

Tags: flash

The vulnerabilities even in patched Adobe Flash are getting out of hand and we have been wondering of disabling it for the time being. Very few services actually require flash nowadays, so having it disabled by default wont propably have huge impact. The question is, how to actually do that. Users have IE, Firefox and Chrome and each of those has a different way to manually disable flash. What im looking for is a way/script/setting/GPO that could be ran on every computer which would disable flash on them. But so far, I havent found anything useful.

Is this possible? Browsers arent very good with centralized control apart from IE, but even there I dont think I can manage plugins via GPO.

Comment: a cheap method i had for disabling an array of scripting and other stuff in XP before they started patching things was to rename the DLL and EXE items in a batch to something only i knew (because I made the batch) It was just as easy to revert it with the same batch (toggle) turning it all back on by renaming the files back to the orignal names. If a person had permission, if the system would not freak out, if they admin the computers the same basic thing could be done, and no wandeing viruses would know the names of the renamed files.  Lame but effective.

Comment: If users are unable to install software then they are unable to install Flash if it isn't installed.  Control browser configuration through a group policy.

Comment: I dont want to uninstall flash totally, but just to disable it from browsers. Firefox/Chrome cannot be controlled via GPO.